# Get value of mysql database in select menu

Tags: php, mysql, session, relational-database

I have issue with select menu on PHP. I tried to get mysql database to select menu. However, it displays none.

Here is my code:
           
            default:

```
        mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
        $query_Rsenroll = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_enroll` WHERE `tbl_enroll`.`courseid` ='".$_GET['courseid']."'";
        $Rsenroll = mysql_query($query_Rsenroll, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_Rsenroll = mysql_fetch_assoc($Rsenroll);
        $totalRows_Rsenroll = mysql_num_rows($Rsenroll);
   $courseid = $row_Rsenroll['courseid'];
   $er_staffid = "";

        break;
        }
    ?>

        <select name="courseid">
        <option value="" SELECTED>Selected Course ID</option>
          <?php 
    foreach( $Course as $course_id) {
        if ( $course_id == $courseid) {
            $selected = " SELECTED";
        } else {
            $selected = "";
        }
            ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $course_id; ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $row_Rsenroll['courseid']; ?></option>
         <?php
    }
    ?>
        </select>
```

Thank you for any help and advice.

Comment: Can you post your database content?

Comment: Database create 'tbl_enroll" included erid, courseid, staffid

Comment: How many number rows are you getting back?

Comment: 6 rows, I created the tbl_course included 4 courses and select from  tbl_course courseid and insert to tbl_enroll table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming courseid is being passed as a variable in the sending URL (file.php?courseid=COURSEID), I think this should do what you want:

This might clean up your script a little (though I switched it to mysql_fetch_array as I'm more familiar with that than mysql_fetch_assoc. Feel free to use assoc):

```
   <?php
   $cid = '6116';
   ?>


   <select name="courseidMenu">
   <option value="" SELECTED>Selected Course ID</option> 
   <?php

   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_enroll WHERE courseid = '$cid'", $conn)or die(mysql_error());
   $total_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      $courseId = $row['courseid'];
      ?>
      <option value="<?=$courseId?>" ><?=$courseId?></option>      
      <?

   }
   ?>
   </select>
```

Comment: I've updated and tested this script. Try that out, setting $cid to a value in your database that will appear for courseid.

Answer (score 0):

```
updated    use this it is working on my portal                           <select>
        <option value=''>Select Provider</option>
        <?php
        $server="server name";
        $user="user name";
        $password="password";
        $database="database";
        $conn=mysql_connect($server,$user,$password) or die("connection failed");
        mysql_select_db($database,$conn);
        $query_Rsenroll = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_enroll` WHERE `tbl_enroll`.`courseid` ='".$_GET['courseid']."'";
        $result= mysql_query($query_Rsenroll, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
        $n=mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($n>0)
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
        echo"<option value='$row['courseid']'>$row['courseid']</option>";
        mysql_close($conn);
        ?>
```

Comment: I tried to follow your code. It doesnot work on. It displays nothing

Comment: check your query                                                      print your query on browser   then   run it on phpmyadmin or terminal            then see result because your query may be incorrect .